# Compilation error occurred in qiskit natural gradient case

Tags: qiskit

https://learn.qiskit.org/summer-school/2021/lab4-introduction-training-quantum-circuits

```
  > TranspilerError                           Traceback (most recent call
    > last) File
    > d:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\opflow\gradients\circuit_gradients\circuit_gradient.py:92,
    > in CircuitGradient._transpile_to_supported_operations(circuit,
    > supported_gates)
    >      91 try:
    > ---> 92     circuit = transpile(
    >      93         circuit, basis_gates=list(supported_gates), optimization_level=0
    >      94     )
    >      95 except Exception as exc:
    > 
    > File
    > d:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\compiler\transpiler.py:304, in
    > transpile(circuits, backend, basis_gates, inst_map, coupling_map,
    > backend_properties, initial_layout, layout_method, routing_method,
    > translation_method, scheduling_method, instruction_durations, dt,
    > approximation_degree, timing_constraints, seed_transpiler,
    > optimization_level, callback, output_name, unitary_synthesis_method,
    > unitary_synthesis_plugin_config, target)
    >     303 # Transpile circuits in parallel
    > --> 304 circuits = parallel_map(_transpile_circuit, list(zip(circuits, transpile_args)))
    >     306 end_time = time()
    > 
    > File d:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\tools\parallel.py:129, in
    > parallel_map(task, values, task_args, task_kwargs, num_processes)
    >     128 if len(values) == 1:
    > --> 129     return [task(values[0], *task_args, **task_kwargs)]
    >     131 Publisher().publish("terra.parallel.start", len(values))
    > 
    > File
    > d:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\compiler\transpiler.py:389, in
    > _transpile_circuit(circuit_config_tuple)
    >     387     raise TranspilerError("optimization_level can range from 0 to 3.")
    > --> 389 result = pass_manager.run(
    >     390     circuit, callback=transpile_config["callback"], output_name=transpile_config["output_name"]
    >     391 )
    >     393 if transpile_config["faulty_qubits_map"]:
    > 
    > File
    > d:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\transpiler\passmanager.py:222,
    > in PassManager.run(self, circuits, output_name, callback)
    >     221 if isinstance(circuits, QuantumCircuit):
    > --> 222     return self._run_single_circuit(circuits, output_name, callback)
    >     223 if len(circuits) == 1:
    > 
    > File
    > d:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\transpiler\passmanager.py:277,
    > in PassManager._run_single_circuit(self, circuit, output_name,
    > callback)
    >     276 running_passmanager = self._create_running_passmanager()
    > --> 277 result = running_passmanager.run(circuit, output_name=output_name, callback=callback)
    >     278 self.property_set = running_passmanager.property_set
    > 
    > File
    > d:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\transpiler\runningpassmanager.py:124,
    > in RunningPassManager.run(***failed resolving arguments***)
    >     123     for pass_ in passset:
    > --> 124         dag = self._do_pass(pass_, dag, passset.options)
    >     126 circuit = dag_to_circuit(dag)
    > 
    > File
    > d:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\transpiler\runningpassmanager.py:157,
    > in RunningPassManager._do_pass(self, pass_, dag, options)
    >     156 if pass_ not in self.valid_passes:
    > --> 157     dag = self._run_this_pass(pass_, dag)
    >     159     # update the valid_passes property
    > 
    > File
    > d:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\transpiler\runningpassmanager.py:186,
    > in RunningPassManager._run_this_pass(self, pass_, dag)
    >     185 start_time = time()
    > --> 186 new_dag = pass_.run(dag)
    >     187 end_time = time()
    > 
    > File
    > d:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\transpiler\passes\basis\basis_translator.py:206,
    > in BasisTranslator.run(self, dag)
    >     205 if basis_transforms is None:
    > --> 206     raise TranspilerError(
    >     207         "Unable to map source basis {} to target basis {} "
    >     208         "over library {}.".format(source_basis, target_basis, self._equiv_lib)
    >     209     )
    >     211 # Compose found path into a set of instruction substitution rules.
    > 
    > TranspilerError: "Unable to map source basis {('h', 1),
    > ('save_density_matrix', 3), ('swap', 2), ('ry', 1), ('ccx', 3),
    > ('barrier', 18), ('cx', 2)} to target basis {'rz', 'ry', 'y',
    > 'barrier', 'u', 'snapshot', 'h', 'z', 'measure', 'x', 'cx', 'delay',
    > 'cz', 'reset', 'p', 'rx', 'cy'} over library
    > <qiskit.circuit.equivalence.EquivalenceLibrary object at
    > 0x000001D80DDAD310>."
    > 
    > The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    > 
    > QiskitError                               Traceback (most recent call
    > last) Input In [13], in <cell line: 41>()
    >      38 print(finite_difference)
    >      40 shifter = Gradient()  # parameter-shift rule is the default
    > ---> 41 grad = shifter.convert(expectation, params=QC.parameters[index])
    >      42 sampler.convert(grad, value_dict).eval().real
    >      44 tmp = init_states(num_words, qbits_for_single_word) 
    > 
    > File
    > d:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\opflow\gradients\gradient.py:78,
    > in Gradient.convert(self, operator, params)
    >      76 expec_op = PauliExpectation(group_paulis=False).convert(operator).reduce()
    >      77 cleaned_op = self._factor_coeffs_out_of_composed_op(expec_op)
    > ---> 78 return self.get_gradient(cleaned_op, param)
    > 
    > File
    > d:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\opflow\gradients\gradient.py:182,
    > in Gradient.get_gradient(self, operator, params)
    >     176     if not isinstance(operator[-1], CircuitStateFn):
    >     177         raise TypeError(
    >     178             "The gradient framework is compatible with states that are given as "
    >     179             "CircuitStateFn"
    >     180         )
    > --> 182     return self.grad_method.convert(operator, param)
    >     184 elif isinstance(operator, CircuitStateFn):
    >     185     # Gradient of an a state's sampling probabilities
    >     186     if not is_coeff_c(operator._coeff, 1.0):
    > 
    > File
    > d:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\opflow\gradients\circuit_gradients\param_shift.py:116,
    > in ParamShift.convert(self, operator, params)
    >      96 """
    >      97 Args:
    >      98     operator: The operator corresponding to our quantum state we are taking the    (...)
    >     113 
    >     114 """
    >     115 if isinstance(params, (ParameterExpression, ParameterVector)):
    > --> 116     return self._parameter_shift(operator, params)
    >     117 elif isinstance(params, tuple):
    >     118     return self._parameter_shift(self._parameter_shift(operator, params[0]),
    > params[1])
    > 
    > File
    > d:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\opflow\gradients\circuit_gradients\param_shift.py:202,
    > in ParamShift._parameter_shift(self, operator, params)
    >     197 circ = circs[0]
    >     199 if self.analytic:
    >     200     # Unroll the circuit into a gate set for which the gradient may be computed
    >     201     # using pi/2 shifts.
    > --> 202     circ = ParamShift._transpile_to_supported_operations(circ, self.SUPPORTED_GATES)
    >     203     operator = ParamShift._replace_operator_circuit(operator, circ)
    >     205 if param not in circ._parameter_table:
    > 
    > File
    > d:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\opflow\gradients\circuit_gradients\circuit_gradient.py:96,
    > in CircuitGradient._transpile_to_supported_operations(circuit,
    > supported_gates)
    >      92         circuit = transpile(
    >      93             circuit, basis_gates=list(supported_gates), optimization_level=0
    >      94         )
    >      95     except Exception as exc:
    > ---> 96         raise QiskitError(
    >      97             f"Could not transpile the circuit provided {circuit} into supported gates "
    >      98             f"{supported_gates}."
    >      99         ) from exc
    >     100 return circuit
    > 
    > QiskitError: "Could not transpile the circuit provided (....QC) into supported gates {'rz', 'ry', 'y', 'u', 'h', 'z', 'x', 'cx', 'cz', 'p', 'rx', 'cy'}."
```

When experimenting with the Lab-4 case of the qiskit2021 summer machine learning school, the quantum circuit in the notebook of Lab-4 was replaced (the circuit is not convenient to provide), the structure is much more complicated than the provided case, and the following problems occur when compiling

> Unable to map source basis {('h', 1),
> ('save_density_matrix', 3), ('swap', 2), ('ry', 1), ('ccx', 3),
> ('barrier', 18), ('cx', 2)} to target basis {'rz', 'ry', 'y',
> 'barrier', 'u', 'snapshot', 'h', 'z', 'measure', 'x', 'cx', 'delay',
> 'cz', 'reset', 'p', 'rx', 'cy'} over library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to this line

```
TranspilerError: "Unable to map source basis {('h', 1),
    > ('save_density_matrix', 3), ('swap', 2), ('ry', 1), ('ccx', 3),
    > ('barrier', 18), ('cx', 2)} to target basis {'rz', 'ry', 'y',
    > 'barrier', 'u', 'snapshot', 'h', 'z', 'measure', 'x', 'cx', 'delay',
    > 'cz', 'reset', 'p', 'rx', 'cy'} over library
    > <qiskit.circuit.equivalence.EquivalenceLibrary object at
    > 0x000001D80DDAD310>."
```

it happen is because your source basis have `save_density_matrix`, you should add it to your supported_gates also. always check Error message to understand the reason.